# Custom layout handle for email

Tags: layout, email-templates

I've created a module that sends custom emails. I've tried to add a custom layout handle in the email template
`{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items_no_price" order=$order}}`
Where should I place the new layout? I know I shouldn't touch `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml`
I tried to place it in `app/design/frontend/mypackage/default/etc/theme.xml` but it doesn't seem to be working. 
Sorry for the beginner question.

Answer (score 1):

I literally almost answered my own question:
I've placed it now in
`app/design/frontend/mypackage/default/layout/sales.xml' and it seem to have worked.

Is that the right way to do it? I've read some articles custom layouts should go into`local.xml' (no longer recommended), or theme.xml (for 1.9), that's why I got confused. Can anyone help me to understand in what cases theme.xml should be used rather than use the fall back to overload sales.xml? Thanks.

Further more, I'd like to load my own phtml in that layout handle, ie, I want to replace `email/order/items.phtml` and `email/order/items/order/default.phtml` with my own (under different name), where should they go? `email/order/items.phtml` seem to live under `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/email/order`, not sure where I can place the alternative.